# How to install custom hit beep sounds for TF2? (aka dingaling)

Tags: team-fortress-2, windows

I've just reinstalled TF2 and I used to have the Quake 4 sounds playing when hitting people, which was great. Now I'm back to vanilla.

I've [found](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Quake%204%20hitbeep.wav) the hitbeep I wanted, how do I go about to installing it?

Comment: Is this melee only or does it trigger anytime you do damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open this folder:

```
...\Steam\steamapps\common\team fortress 2\tf\custom\myleetdingaling\sound\ui
```

(...where `myleetdingaling` can be anything at all.)

Put the file here and make sure it's called `hitbeep.wav`. If your hitbeep is an MP3 file (or something other than a Wave file), [you can convert it to the .wav format with VLC.](https://superuser.com/questions/28333/how-to-convert-media-using-vlc)